# I am working with a Dataset, where few values in the Date Column are like ' 2 Months Ago', ' 28 Days Ago', how can we change these dates to Month-Year

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataset, data-science

[image: This is the Column, how can we get it the same way as some other Columns are in the format of Month-Year]

I am thinking of trying if condition, but is there any library or method which I don't know about can solve this?

Comment: What is expected ouput from `4 months ago` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract actual month-year period with months from values with decimals with `month(s)` and assign back to DataFrames, for days convert values to timedeltas and subtract actual datetime by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side:

```
print (df)
             col
0    28 days ago
1   4 months ago
2  11 months ago
3      Oct, 2021

now = pd.Timestamp('now')
per = now.to_period('m')
date = now.floor('d')

s = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*month', expand=False).astype(float)
s1 = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*day', expand=False).astype(float)

mask, mask1 = s.notna(), s1.notna()
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = s[mask].astype(int).rsub(per).dt.strftime('%b, %Y')
df.loc[mask1, 'col'] = pd.to_timedelta(s1[mask1], unit='d').rsub(date).dt.strftime('%b, %Y')
print (df)
         col
0  Sep, 2022
1  Jun, 2022
2  Nov, 2021
3  Oct, 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
            col
0  4 months ago
1     Oct, 2021
2  9 months ago
```

You can use:

```
# try to get a date:
s = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors='coerce')

# extract the month offset
offset = (df['col']
          .str.extract(r'(\d+) months? ago', expand=False)
          .fillna(0).astype(int)
         )

# if the date it NaT, replace by today - n months
df['date'] = s.fillna(pd.Timestamp('today').normalize()
                    - offset*pd.DateOffset(months=1))
```

If you want a Mon, Year format:

```
df['date2'] = df['col'].where(offset.eq(0),
                             (pd.Timestamp('today').normalize()
                             -offset*pd.DateOffset(months=1)
                             ).dt.strftime('%b, %Y')
                             )
```

output:

```
            col       date      date2
0  4 months ago 2022-06-28  Jun, 2022
1     Oct, 2021 2021-10-01  Oct, 2021
2  9 months ago 2022-01-28  Jan, 2022
```